# Measuring elapsed time remotely

Tags: network-programming, timing

I have a program which measures the time a student takes to perform a task.
The program is connected to the Internet and the student with the lowest time gets a prize on the website.

Given that the PC could measure time incorrectly (I've seen it happen) or the student could preload a shared library to intercept the OS calls and give phony times, the timing needs to be performed on the server side.

Currently my logic goes like this:

1. Client signals server to start.
2. Server records time and sends ACK back to client.
3. Client starts task after receiving ACK.
4. Client finishes task and sends notification to server.
5. Server records time and calculates elapsed time.

The problem is, this includes the latency from the time the Server sends the ACK to the time the Client receives it + the time the Client finishes to the time the Server receives the message. If the latency is 400ms and the task is 6s long, it makes up a rather large percentage of the total time.

Is there any better way measure the time of the task when the student or the PC may be untrustworthy?

Answer (score 0):

Some competitions require the student or competitor to upload his binary program (or mayb the source code) into your server, which you do control. You could do that. In particular, if it is student code, you probably can require to upload the source code, and restrict to some API, and e.g. run it in a `chroot`-ed environment.

Comment: The student is supposed to answer 10 quickfire maths questions in the shortest time possible - they don't produce resulting binary or code so unfortunately that won't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could do things in Javascript, within the student's browser?

Comment: Unfortunately, with Javascript the user can very easily change what happens, e.g. call their own methods, stop methods from being called, etc. This would not make the timing very reliable.